# How to set focus and set the text in input text using createEvent and dispatchEvent?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, keyboard-events, html.textboxfor

I'm trying to write a code in Javascript, which should set the cursor focus on the input textbox and should trigger a "keypress" event which should set key, say letter 'A' in the textbox.

How to do it? I read we can achieve using `createEvent` and `dispatchEvent`. Any Suggestions?

Comment: What you want ? are you trying to enter key press event chance focus into controls

Comment: Please be clear on what you want!

Comment: I need to trigger a "keypress" event which should set a char key in the text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="text" id="input-field" />

<script>

var addData = function(data){
var field = document.getElementById("input-field")
field.value = document.getElementById("input-field").value+data;

var keyboardEvent = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
var initMethod = typeof keyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent !== 'undefined' ?   "initKeyboardEvent" : "initKeyEvent";


keyboardEvent[initMethod](
               "keypress", // event type : keydown, keyup, keypress
                true, // bubbles
                true, // cancelable
                window, // viewArg: should be window
                false, // ctrlKeyArg
                false, // altKeyArg
                false, // shiftKeyArg
                false, // metaKeyArg
                40, // keyCodeArg : unsigned long the virtual key code, else 0
                0 // charCodeArgs : unsigned long the Unicode character associated with the depressed key, else 0
);
field.dispatchEvent(keyboardEvent);

}

 var registerEvents = function(){
 document.getElementById("input-field").addEventListener("keypress",function(event){
    alert("Key Pressed : "+ event.target.value)
 });
}();
addData("a");
addData("b");

</script>
```

Anyways Entered key will be available in text field, no need to set it explicitly.

Comment: no input will be entered manually into textbox. we need to set text using javascript. How to do it ?

Comment: check now, I have made an edit

Comment: Thanks @Sabith for the answer. I need to clarify one thing in the above code. you have used                                                                        field.value = document.getElementById("input-field").value+data; which explicitly sets the textbox value with the data passed. Is it not possible for the text box to be updated the text itself when we trigger the "keypress" event ?

Comment: here we are simulating the keyborad event only. if we enter something to the input field, input field will be populated with that value and then trigger the event. thats the default behaviour. 
Instead we are simply triggering the event without value. so it will not populate itslef, we have to append ourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion !!! your answer is appreciated !